# flutter mockito throws type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'Future<Response>'

Tags: flutter

I am trying to use mockito to mock a http client and return some values based on the Uri. I have the following code but got `type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'Future<Response>'` error.

```
  Future<MockHttpClientBuilder> withListPostEndpoint() async {
    Uri uri = Uri(
        scheme: 'https',
        host: this._host,
        path: '/Posts',
        query: 'sortBy=CreatedAt&sortOrder=Descending&pageSize=15&pageOffset=0');
    //Uri uri = Uri.parse('https://localhost/Posts?sortBy=CreatedAt&sortOrder=Descending&pageSize=15&pageOffset=0');

    String content = await File('test/shared/mock_http_client_payloads/list_post_response.json').readAsString();

    Map<String, String> headers = new Map();
    headers[HttpHeaders.contentTypeHeader] = 'application/json';

    when(_client.get(uri, headers: headers)).thenAnswer((_) async => Response(content, 200));

    return this;
  }
```

I tried to use two different ways to generate Uri object (one is them is commented). From the error message, the error happens at line `when(_client.get(uri, headers: headers)).thenAnswer((_) async => Response(content, 200));`.

In addition, the error happens before the mocked endpoint is actually called. Seems like the error happens when the mock endpoint is setup. I put the breakpoint at the production code where the endpoint is called but the breakpoint is not reaches.

Can anyone please help to have a look? Thank you

Comment: Can you provide a minimal, reproducible example?  Also, if you're using `package:http`, is there a reason you're not using its own [`MockClient` class](https://pub.dev/documentation/http/latest/http.testing/MockClient-class.html) instead?

Comment: Thank you jamesdlin. I find that I did not run `dart run build_runner build`. When the mock is generated, the error is solved.

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to run `dart run build_runner build` to generate the mock file. After running the command, the error is resolved.